# Sick Baby Leopard Gecko

Tags: reptiles

Long story short, I was given a sick baby leopard gecko because I was the only person that the owner of the pet store know that would take good care of it since I already have 3 leopard geckos.

The baby leopard gecko is extremely skinny and has stick tail I believe. It won’t eat and looks very weak. Is there anything I can do for it to start eating?

(It’s currently in a 10 gallon with paper towels. I put in the bowl of small baby mealworms mixed with calcium just in case if it’s interested.)